Should I replace the sleeve of my water heater heating element?
I have a storage-type hot water heater using a steatite heating element. After performing maintenance on it, I noticed the protective sleeve of the heating element is a bit rusty. There is also a buildscup of scale.
  
Considering the cost of a new sleeve (about €90 ~ $100), and the additional operating cost incured by the scale buildup, should I replace it because of the corrosion and the scale buildup?
Scale buildup can lead to an increased electricity consumption. I removed most of the scale, but I don’t know whether what remains will have a noticeable impact.
It is probably possible to remove the scale, but some of the manuals I found warned against using chemical products. I am afraid to remove the scale with a chisel.
Also, I am afraid that a leak in the cover damages the heating elements or the electronic components underneath.
Additional details
The water heater is in France. It has a capacity of 250 liters. It uses a steatite heating element. It is also, I believe, older than 10 years old.
I am performing long-overdue maintenance on it, replacing the anode, adding dielectric unions, as well as replacing the hydraulic safety group with a new one.
The interior of the tank seems in pretty good shape to me.
  
Research done
Some of my research included:

I tried consulting the hot water tank manual. It wasn’t the exact same reference, but one manual I found was similar enough. It said the interior of the hot water tank shouldn’t be cleaned with any chemical product, which makes it seem impossible to remove the scale build-up from the sleeve.
Thermor article on how steatite heating elements work, and their use cases.


Where exactly is the rust on the bottom picture?  If on the tank itself, the price of a new sleeve might not be worth it.

It’s on the tank itself, right at the junction between the base and the middle part (if that makes sense).

Outside of the tank, you might be able to use a rust stopper and paint, to get a few more safe years.  Inside, I do not know of safe stuff to use with water, so you are on borrowed time before a leak.

The only possible answers from here are opinion-based. We don't know how thick the metal sleeve is and how close it is to perforation. You need to weigh the risks of damage to your property from leakage, including damage to the heating element itself, which could last many more years in a new sleeve.

Thank you. . I am asking for an answer that relies either on personal experience or some reference that could guide the correct action, as the question is not documented anywhere and I don’t have the experience to judge. I tried clarifying the question after your comment. While it is not possible to predict the future, I think that if someone had a similar experience his or her answer will provide a very satisfying and useful answer about the generally correct course of actions.
